# How do I share the information I want by image instead of text

Tags: android

I have a sports application, and on the page calculate the goals of the game, for example football ..., I have the option to share the result in the form of text.

I want to know how to share information arranged in a picture to other apps?

Comment: So, let me get this correct. you want your text result to be converted to image file and share??

Comment: The answer to this question shows how to draw text into a bitmap: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32177375/how-to-draw-on-canvas-and-convert-to-bitmap

Comment: @RonDaulagupu Yes, that's what I want

Comment: you can do in 2 ways. one create a bitmap canvas and draw your text there. @JimRhodes has given a nice example or do a screenshot of the screen if that's what you prefer. Link to both: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624133/how-to-take-a-screen-shot-on-a-button-click-can-anyone-provide-a-android-code/38157486 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973048/convert-text-to-image-file-on-android

Comment: @RonDaulagupu Ok , thank you